# IIS 5 or 6 and the HTTP protocol with WCF?

Tags: wcf

Does IIS 5 or 6 still have the limitation of only being able to use the HTTP Protocol in a WCF Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use bindings others than the HTTP-based ones in IIS, you'll have to use WAS but it is available only for IIS 7.0+ (Win 2008+)